# How to make Zepto compatible with Browserify?

Tags: javascript, zepto, browserify

I made some changes to Zepto and hope I can use it in Browserify:

```
➤➤ git diff
diff --git a/package.json b/package.json
index 294af90..e4f8fd1 100644
--- a/package.json
+++ b/package.json
@@ -7,6 +7,7 @@
     , "dist": "coffee make dist"
     , "start": "coffee test/server.coffee"
   }
+  , "main": "dist/zepto.js"
   , "repository": {
       "type": "git"
     , "url": "https://github.com/madrobby/zepto.git"
diff --git a/src/zepto.js b/src/zepto.js
index 93bfe18..cdf8929 100644
--- a/src/zepto.js
+++ b/src/zepto.js
@@ -787,6 +787,17 @@ var Zepto = (function() {
   return $
 })()

-// If `$` is not yet defined, point it to `Zepto`
-window.Zepto = Zepto
-'$' in window || (window.$ = Zepto)
+// detect module loader like jQuery
+// http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js
+if ( typeof module === "object" && module && typeof module.exports === "object" ) {
+  module.exports = Zepto;
+} else {
+  if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
+    define( "zepto", [], function () { return Zepto; } );
+  }
+}
+if ( typeof window === "object" && typeof window.document === "object" ) {
+  window.Zepto = Zepto
+  // If `$` is not yet defined, point it to `Zepto`
+  '$' in window || (window.$ = Zepto)  
+}
```

But I got errors:

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:91
                        var dir = path.resolve(x, pkg.main);
                                                     ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'main' of undefined
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:91:54
    at load (/usr/lib/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:54:43)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:60:22
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:16:47
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: Doe it work when you require the modified file in node.js? I'd first verify if that works. Note that to get it working server-side, you most likely would have to create a `global.window` variable first, pointing to window object from JSDom or so.

Comment: Oh, no, I still want to use it in a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually add `module.exports = window.$` to the bottom of the zepto file or use [browserify-shim](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim) in order to get your modules adapted for browserify on the fly.

I would recommend the latter option since editing 3rd party modules is problematic especially if you plan to upgrade them later.

browserify-shim was [tested to work with zepto in particular](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim/blob/master/test/shim/shim-zepto.js).

Take a moment to study the readme and examples to learn how to properly set things up. You can then of course shim pretty much any library that attaches a variable to the global context, i.e. jquery.

On another note, the errors you got where due to a bug in browserify that has been fixed in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks, I [tried the former](https://github.com/jiyinyiyong/zepto-browserify#zepto-browserify) and it worked. I found it quite hard to understand how Browserify-Shim is working. I did as was described in the README before, but failed to create a package of Zepto.

Comment: Did I make mistakes? Is browserify used in bundling libraries like jQuery into a module, or just require them every time I bundle a whole  piece of code (which means every time I have to modify the script for doing that)?

Comment: browserify-shim does not generate a separate module. Instead it just wraps the code (i.e. zepto's) before it gets added to the bundle. That wrapper makes it commonJS compat. Also browserify-shim was designed so you **wouldn't have to create custom libs** just to get commonsJS compatibility. So it's not made for what you are referring to in your example, but to not have to do that ;)

Comment: Got it. Thanks and I'll close this question now.